# Actualizar y eliminar en una misma función - php

Tags: php

Tengo una función en php donde quiero que me actualice los productos y me elimine el contenido de una tabla, pero no me funciona los dos query al mismo tiempo. Si agrego el query de borrar, solo me esta eliminando el contenido del query eliminar, pero no me esta actualizando los productos.

```php
static public function mdlEditarProducto($tabla, $datos){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare(
        "UPDATE $tabla SET id_categoria = :id_categoria, id_subcategoria = :id_subcategoria, 
        tipo = :tipo, ruta = :ruta, estado = :estado, titulo = :titulo, titular = :titular, 
        descripcion = :descripcion, multimedia = :multimedia, detalles = :detalles, 
        precio = :precio, portada = :portada, oferta = :oferta, precioOferta = :precioOferta, 
        descuentoOferta = :descuentoOferta, imgOferta = :imgOferta, finOferta = :finOferta, 
        peso = :peso, entrega = :entrega WHERE id = :id"
    );

    $stmt->bindParam(":id_categoria", $datos["idCategoria"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_subcategoria", $datos["idSubCategoria"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tipo", $datos["tipo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":ruta", $datos["ruta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":estado", $datos["estado"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":titulo", $datos["titulo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":titular", $datos["titular"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":descripcion", $datos["descripcion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":multimedia", $datos["multimedia"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":detalles", $datos["detalles"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":precio", $datos["precio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":portada", $datos["imgFotoPrincipal"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":oferta", $datos["oferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":precioOferta", $datos["precioOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":descuentoOferta", $datos["descuentoOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":imgOferta", $datos["imgOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":finOferta", $datos["finOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":peso", $datos["peso"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":entrega", $datos["entrega"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

   //BORRAR DATOS TABLA dtl_product

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM dtl_product WHERE idPro_dtl = :id");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return $datos["id"];
    }else{
        return "error";
    }
    $stmt = null;
}
```

Comment: Hola. En informática hay algo que se llama *principio de responsabilidad única*, lo que intentas hacer aquí viola ese principio y no es buena idea, aunque parezca maravilloso *matar dos pájaros de un tiro*. Si lees sobre el tema entenderás por qué, ese principio te conduce a una *separación de responsabilidades* y ahí está el *quid* de la cuestión en este caso. La segunda acción, que aquí sería borrar un registro a partir de una actualización, **debe ser responsabilidad de la base de datos**, allí deberías programar un `TRIGGER` que se dispare después del `UPDATE` y haga el `DELETE`.

Comment: Si me he explicado bien, la gravedad del asunto aquí sería que, irrespetando el principio de responsabilidad única, algo que debería hacer la base de datos (disparando un `TRIGGER` después del `UPDATE`) decides hacerlo por ti mismo, intentando reinventar la rueda, con toda la pérdida de tiempo que ello supone, con un código kilométrico y que podría provocar errores e inconsistencias en los datos. Y no hablemos del mantenimiento, del cuidado que hay que tener para llamar a ese código etc. ¿Por qué meterse en ese berenjenal? En la BD el `TRIGGER`se disparará él solito, cada vez que haya UPDATE.

Comment: buen día, necesito cuadrar el código que tengo y no en la base de datos ya que me puede alterar algunas cosas en el proyecto,

Comment: No debería descuadrar nada. Si necesitas borrar datos en una tabla una vez haya ocurrido un `UPDATE` y planteas escribir en PHP un código que hago eso, OK, puedes hacerlo, pero yo te sugiero que escribas un TRIGGER en la base de datos que lo haga, a no ser que no tengas acceso o permisos suficientes en la BD, o no te autoricen a ello, etc. Sea como sea, si no puedes escribir el TRIGGER por lo que sea, en la pregunta muestra todo el contexto (por ejemplo, no se ve ningún DELETE ahí), pero no olvides que, aunque lo logres en PHP este no es el camino, por todo lo dicho más arriba.

Comment: te entiendo, pero si me puedes colaborar con lo que necesito te lo agradeciera.

Comment: El problema que veo ahí es que no estás ejecutando la consulta `UPDATE`, después de todos los `bindParam` tendrías que poner esto: **`$stmt->execute();`** Si analizas bien, estás usando dos veces `$stmt`, una vez para preparar el `UPDATE`  y  otra vez para preparar el `DELETE`, cuando lo correcto es ejecutar cada una para que las acciones se realicen.

Comment: me podrías colaborar con mi código como quedaría la verdad sigo con el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás ejecutando el `$stmt` en la parte del `UPDATE`.

```
static public function mdlEditarProducto($tabla, $datos){  
      
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET id_categoria = :id_categoria, id_subcategoria = :id_subcategoria, tipo = :tipo, ruta = :ruta, estado = :estado, titulo = :titulo, titular = :titular, descripcion = :descripcion, multimedia = :multimedia, detalles = :detalles, precio = :precio, portada = :portada, oferta = :oferta, precioOferta = :precioOferta, descuentoOferta = :descuentoOferta, imgOferta = :imgOferta, finOferta = :finOferta, peso = :peso, entrega = :entrega WHERE id = :id");       

        $stmt->bindParam(":id_categoria", $datos["idCategoria"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_subcategoria", $datos["idSubCategoria"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tipo", $datos["tipo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ruta", $datos["ruta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":estado", $datos["estado"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":titulo", $datos["titulo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":titular", $datos["titular"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":descripcion", $datos["descripcion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":multimedia", $datos["multimedia"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":detalles", $datos["detalles"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":precio", $datos["precio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":portada", $datos["imgFotoPrincipal"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":oferta", $datos["oferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":precioOferta", $datos["precioOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":descuentoOferta", $datos["descuentoOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":imgOferta", $datos["imgOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":finOferta", $datos["finOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":peso", $datos["peso"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":entrega", $datos["entrega"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        //ESTO FALTA
        $stmt->execute();
  
       //BORRAR DATOS TABLA dtl_product
       //AQUÍ $stmt es un nuevo objeto
       //No tiene nada que ver con el anterior
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM dtl_product WHERE idPro_dtl  = :id");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);           
     
       if($stmt->execute()){
           $stmt = null;
           return $datos["id"];
       }else{
           return "error";
       }
}
```

Si el `DELETE` no debe ocurrir si el `UPDATE` falla, entonces deberías hacer algo así:

```
static public function mdlEditarProducto($tabla, $datos){
        //Variable para controlar la salida
        $outPut="";
       
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET id_categoria = :id_categoria, id_subcategoria = :id_subcategoria, tipo = :tipo, ruta = :ruta, estado = :estado, titulo = :titulo, titular = :titular, descripcion = :descripcion, multimedia = :multimedia, detalles = :detalles, precio = :precio, portada = :portada, oferta = :oferta, precioOferta = :precioOferta, descuentoOferta = :descuentoOferta, imgOferta = :imgOferta, finOferta = :finOferta, peso = :peso, entrega = :entrega WHERE id = :id");       

        $stmt->bindParam(":id_categoria", $datos["idCategoria"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_subcategoria", $datos["idSubCategoria"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tipo", $datos["tipo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ruta", $datos["ruta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":estado", $datos["estado"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":titulo", $datos["titulo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":titular", $datos["titular"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":descripcion", $datos["descripcion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":multimedia", $datos["multimedia"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":detalles", $datos["detalles"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":precio", $datos["precio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":portada", $datos["imgFotoPrincipal"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":oferta", $datos["oferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":precioOferta", $datos["precioOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":descuentoOferta", $datos["descuentoOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":imgOferta", $datos["imgOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":finOferta", $datos["finOferta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":peso", $datos["peso"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":entrega", $datos["entrega"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        //ESTO FALTA
        if ( $stmt->execute() && $stmt->rowCount()>0 ) {    

           //BORRAR DATOS TABLA dtl_product
           //AQUÍ $stmt es un nuevo objeto
           //No tiene nada que ver con el anterior
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM dtl_product WHERE idPro_dtl  = :id");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);           
     
            if( $stmt->execute() && $stmt->rowCount()>0 ) {
                $outPut=$datos["id"];
            } else {
                $outPut="error en el delete";
            }
        } else {    
            $outPut="error en el update";   
        }
    $stmt=null;
    return $outPut;    
}
```

**PD**: Cuando uses `return` en el código, considera que todo lo que estés después de `return` no se ejecutará. En casos donde debas hacer varias evaluaciones lo más limpio es usar una variable en la que irás recogiendo todas las salidas posibles y hacer `return` de esa variable al final. En el segundo bloque de la respuesta he usado una variable `$outPut` para ello.